# How to change KendoUI Fields value

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui

It seems that kendoUI scheduler can't display local time correctly unless date format like this

```
      2016/03/07T08:30:00.000Z
```

json

```
[{
  "iGuid": 1,
  "taskId": 1,
  "OwnerID": "1",
  "StartTimezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "EndTimezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "Description": "A",
  "RecurrenceID": null,
  "RecurrenceRule": null,
  "RecurrenceException": null,
  "Subcode": "A",
  "Start": "2016-03-07 08:30:00",
  "End": "2016-03-07 12:30:00",
  "Title": "A",
  "IsAllDay": false
}]
```

scheduler schema

```
  schema: {
              model: {
                  id: "taskId",
                  fields: {
                       iGuid : {from : "iGuid"},
                       taskId: { from: "taskId" }, 
                       ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },                                  
                       startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                       endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                       description: { from: "Description" },
                       recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                       recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                       recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                       start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                       end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                    },

                    }
                }
            }
```

Does it has any way to convert ,and it isn't work in vb ?

(I did it in vb .by using "Replace","Trim", and etc to convert)

Because I want to learn other front-end ways.

Thanks for  your help.